# Unable to read secret from Azure Key Vault from Azure Service Fabric App

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault

I am trying to read a secret from Azure KeyVault from a Service Fabric application. It seems like when I am running in Visual Studio that ServiceFabric is not leveraging my Azure AD account in Visual Studio to authenticate. It is failing on trying to use Environment Variables or Managed Identity. **Is there a different way this should be done in a Service Fabric app?**

```
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(_Environment.ContentRootPath)
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddEnvironmentVariables();


    var keyValutName = Configuration["KeyVaultName"];
    builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
          new SecretClient(
             new Uri($"https://{keyValutName}.vault.azure.net/"),
             new DefaultAzureCredential()),
          new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
        );

    Configuration = builder.Build();
```

I receive the following error message:

> Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: 'DefaultAzureCredential
> failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the
> troubleshooting guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
>
> - EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable.
>
> Environment variables are not fully configured. See the
> troubleshooting guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
>
> - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
>
> Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: "when I am running in Visual Studio" - Minor point, but I don't think Service Fabric runs in a child process to Visual Studio during a debugging session in the same way as debugging other types of applications. It runs in its own process irrespective to whether VS is running or not.

Comment: What happens if you deploy from VS to your local SF Dev Cluster; quit VS and then interrogate it?

Comment: @Deleted - That is a good point and makes sense on why it could not be working with the Visual Studio account. I am not sure though the best way to work around it. I cannot seem to find documentation or examples.

Comment: What is the `service` you are using in the `Service fabric`? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQKfb.png)

Comment: Hi @Harshitha - This is a stateless .net web api

Answer (score 0):

*We can write the key values and add the secrets of Azure Key Vault from Azure Service Fabric App using the* `ApplicationManifest.xml`

[image]

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="KeyVault" DefaultValue="Somekey" />
    <Parameter Name="CertificateName" DefaultValue="TestCertificate" />
  </Parameters>
```

[image]

*As the ApplicationManifest.xml is an xml file , hence we can use the LinQ query and read the xml file. Below is the code snippet for the same.*

```
var xml_doc = XDocument.Load("Path");
var parms = xml_doc.Descendants("Parameter").Select(c => (string)c).ToArray();
```

*Below is the code fetching the params from the ApplicationManifest.xml.*

[image]